# Animate every second div to grow to a different size with a for-each loop in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a table of divs, with two divs per table row with different background colours, eg. Row one has a red div and a yellow div, row two then also has a red div and a yellow div.

I have a jquery for each loop to loop data from a controller, which is put into the divs, and then assigns a specific animation to the div within the loop, specifically data that determines how large the div will grow in width like a bar graph.

The issue I'm having is that the loop applies the specific animation to all previous div's, and not just the new div we are looping for.

Use case:

- A table row holds two divs.
- Upon loading the table, the second (yellow) div of the first row grows to 30%
- In the next row, the second (yellow) div grows to 70%

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var dd = myDataArray;

$.each(dd, function (i, val) {

items = '<tr>' +
'<td width="10%">' + val.year + '</td>' +
'<td height="60">' +
'<div style="background:#ff6b01; width:0%;" class="container">' + val.minSize +
'</div>'
<br />
'<div style="background:#fcc899; width:0%;" class="container">' + val.maxSize + '</div>'
'</td>' +
'</tr>';

 $('tbody').append(items);

 $(document).ready(function () {

      $("tbody div:last-child").animate({ width: val.maxSize + '%' }, 9900);
 });

});
```

In short: Is it possible to animate the second div in a td one way, and then to animate the second div in a new rows td a different way. I have tried using `"tbody div:last-child last"` but it doesn't work, and possibly isn't valid.

Any incite would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried giving your divs different ids or classes so that you can distinguish them from each-other?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using I'd's.

Comment: What about classes? Just give all the divs you want to animate the same class

Comment: Wouldn't animating them by the same class force them all to grow to the same width? I want each rows second div to be a different width from the previous rows second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
var dd = myDataArray;

$.each(dd, function (i, val) {

 items = '<tr>' +
 '<td width="10%">' + val.year + '</td>' +
 '<td height="60">' +
 '<div style="background:#ff6b01; width:0%;" class="container">' + val.minSize +
 '</div>'
  <br />
  '<div style="background:#fcc899; width:0%;" class="container">' + val.maxSize + '</div>'
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>';

  $('tbody').append(items);

  $("tbody div:last").animate({ width: val.maxSize + '%' }, 9900);

});
```

Don't make the second divs animation happen upon page loading, and use last instead of last-child.